# XML Schema version

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I just got one doubt regarding xml schema version. If suppose I am sending xml schema version  1.0 from my application but external system works on schema version 1.1 . Does it make any differences in output processing?

Regards,
Janardhan

Answer (score 1):

You're generally ok using XSD 1.0 features with an XSD processor that supports XSD 1.1.  However, the converse is not true, of course: You cannot use an XSD 1.0 processor for the new XSD 1.1 features such as assertions, conditional type assignment, etc.

See W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 1: Structures [Appendix G: Changes since version 1.0 (non-normative)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#changes).